# How to remove characters from the end of the string?

Tags: matlab

I have a string variable `name` having value `abcd.jpg`.
How can I remove the `.jpg` from that string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the general case (the file extension may have any number of characters, and the file name may contain dots):

```
>> name = 'example.file.html';
>> result = regexprep(name, '\.[^\.]*$', '')

result =

example.file
```

See [`regexprep` documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) or ask me if you're unsure how this works.

Answer (score 3):

For this special case, there is the function [fileparts](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html).

Comment: gives error `Input must be a row vector of characters.`

Comment: `x='name.jpg'` is a row vector of characters. Don't know what else you used as an input argument.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
if(length(name) > 4)
    if(name(length(name)-3:length(name)) == '.jpg')
        name = name(1:length(name)-4);
    end
end
```

Alternatively, if you want to look for any 3 character file extension at the end of a string, you could just check for a `.` character at position `length(name)-3`, like this:

```
if(name(length(name)-3) == '.')
    name = name(1:length(name)-4);
end
```

You can also use the [fileparts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) function as Daniel mentioned like this:

```
[~,name,~] = fileparts(name)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.` at the line `if(name(length(name)-3) == '.')`.

Comment: That means your string is shorter than 4 characters, in which case there's no file extension anyways. You should add an extra if statement checking for the string length. I'll update my answer to show this.

Comment: No. I displayed the string and got `'012abc3cb7503bddef3ff59e0e52fd79.jpg'`

Comment: I just tried it and it worked fine for me. Are you sure you copied the code correctly?

Comment: Yes. my variable was in `name_1(i)` then I ran `name= name_1(i);`

Comment: What is `i`? It looks like you're only assigning a single character of a string to `name`. Assuming `name_1` is a single string, you should do `name = name_1`.

Comment: name_1 is an array, so name_1(i) is a single string

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49265/discussion-between-varun-das-and-leonardblunderbuss)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not asking for any kind of checking of the input, then you can simply use the `end` feature of arrays in matlab to index backwards from the end of the array to ignore the last four elements as follows:

```
name = 'abcd.jpg' % original name
namewithoutfiletype = name(1:end-4) % name without the last four characters
```

Comment: hi, it looks like you're new to SO, but what makes good answers is not only to give valid code, but also explain the OP why this is solving his problem. You're not only helping the OP, but whoever will be reading that question in the future! So could you, please, add a bit of explanation of what you've done in your code?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have edited my answer to include a better description.